# OAuth2 for Exchange server 2013, 2016 and Office 365

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, exchange-server, office365, exchange-server-2013

Can anyone help me on how do I connect to Exchange server (need to connect to 2013, 2016 and Office 365 based on the user account) and get the emails of a User in that Exchange server via OAuth2?
I have gone through few articles describing it 
Here are the list of them
1. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn626019(v=exchg.150).aspx
But I'm bit confused, as those articles are implying different procedures to implement for Exchange 2013, 2016 and Office 365.
I needed a "Client Credential Flow" of OAuth2 to connect to them. But I wanted to have a Single server to server application which can talk to 2013, 2016 and Office 365

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As the 2nd article you linked to says, OAuth2 is only an option for Exchange Online (aka Office 365).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes. They are saying that's the only option. But I need a way to connect Exchange 2013 and Exchange 2016 as well. Do you have any idea? Thank you